# Duplicates in array - possible to solve in o(n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I have created a code which detects duplicates in an array, I think there isn't an algorithm that is faster than this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

    public class Dupe
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            int[] myArray = {1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4};
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

            for (int a : myArray)
            {
                if (!set.add(a))
                {
                    System.out.println(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's in O(n). Would it also be possible to solve this in o(n)?

Comment: Side note: This algorithm will print duplicates several times, e.g. if you have three 2s then the 2 will be printed twice, I don't know if this is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there isn't since you have to go through array at least once, and you are doing it. So , in order to check if you have duplicates you will do it in `O(n) ° F(n)` (can be `+` or `*`)., so only thing you are left with is to make sure you don't increase that speed, so you need to minimize `F(n)` . Checking if something is in `Set` is `O(1)` so you are left with `O(n)`, and thats it.